# Get pymongo .find() result returned as list of lists of a given size

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am working with a MongoDB collection that is too big to be entirely loaded in memory, and I want to work with it using PyMongo.

For each item, I have to make a search in another collection and apply a function to the result.

The first algorithm I came up with was:

```
for document in collection1.find():
     field1 = document['field']
     search = collection2.find({'field': field1})
     # Do some stuff with the search
```

But performing a search for each element simply takes too much time because it has to wait for the server response every time.

To reduce the waiting time per element I'm trying to use batches of -say, 500 - documents at a time.

The only way I found how to do this is using the next() method on a cursor

```
cursor = collection1.find()
while cursor.alive:
     batch_data = []
     for i in range(500):
          batch_data.append(cursor.next())
     fields = [i['field'] for i in bath_data]:
     search = collection2.find({'field': {"$in": fields}})
     # map each result to the correct document and then do my stuff
```

However this seem very hacky. Is there a way to perform a search on a collection and have the result returned as a list of batches of a given size ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are trying to join two collections on a field. If you are using MongoDB 3.2 or later version you can try [$lookup operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in aggregation framework. It is the equivalent of left outer join in relational databases. But I am not sure of that if pymongo supports it or not. If it doesn't support it, maybe you can use $limit and $skip operators not to load all of the collection to the memory. You can reach pymongo documentation from [here.](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html)

Comment: PyMongo doesn't need to do anything to support $lookup, it passes your whole aggregation pipeline to the server, no matter what operators you specify.